# NOR Flash endurance: damage happens during Program or Erase?

Tags: nor-flash, floating-gate

In NOR Flash memories, the endurance of the device is generally measured in (P/E) cycles. [This datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/198/IS25LP032-064-128-463542.pdf) is a typical example.

[image: Table from datasheet. Endurance field has value "100,000 cycles" and mentions JEDEC A117]

My question is, in a P/E cycle, when does the damage occur? If I perform repeated erase operations without interleaved program operations, does that eat up my endurance? How about repeated 'P's without interleaving 'E's?

My vague understanding from reading the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NOR_flash) is that both Programs and Erases involve applying high voltages to some of the terminals of the floating gate mosfet, but only programming involves high currents and "hot carrier injection". No idea if this means something though.

Comment: "How about repeated 'P's without interleaving 'E's".  You really can't do that.  A Flash cell has to be erased before it can be written.  Most Flash devices are erased on a page basis.  Once a page and all of its cells has been erased, you can then write to each cell once and only once.

Answer (score 2):

TI's [MSP430 Flash Memory Characteristics application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slaa334) says:

> **3.2 Flash Endurance**
> […]
> The most common problem is stuck cells caused by charge trapping. Charge trapping occurs in the
> insulating tunnel oxide during erase operations, causing the cell to read a logic 0 although erased. This is
> a self-healing effect and usually detraps automatically in the quiescent period after an erase cycle. During
> endurance testing at Texas Instruments, the flash cells are continuously erased and rewritten. With a
> delay of at least one or two seconds between two erase and write cycles, the flash endurance increases
> significantly during the tests.
> […]
> **3.3 Cumulative Program Time**
> […]
> Writing to the same row too many times can result in write disturb, and erased bits will be programmed as
> well. This produces no physical damage and, after erase, the disturbed bits are programmable as before.
> No long term effects are known.

So erasing is worse.

(Other NOR flashes should behave in the same way.)

Comment: Thanks for the great source. I have to disagree with the interpretation: the report mentions that the most common read error happen right after an erase operation, but it does not follow that repeated erase operations are what caused the flash to be more suscetible to that failure mode in the first place